# Registration page, email or password exist check

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've written a registration page in PHP using prepared statements. My question is a fairly simple one. When a user registers I want to make sure that they aren't registering under the same username or email as another person. Therefore as part of my verification procedure I run two queries, one to check if the email exists and one to check if the username exists. My question is, is there a better method? I feel that running more that one query could somehow sacrifice some performance. Will performance even be noticably affected by such a query? I realise that I could run `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = ? or email = ?",` but I would like the user to know what they got wrong rather than just a generic "Either your username or email is currently being used, feel free to use trial and error to find which it is". It's probably me just being paranoid about speed, but I was just interested to see what everyone else's opinion on the matter is.

Comment: You can check them separately but it's bad for performance.

Comment: Could you plese justify what you are saying? EDIT: Don't mean to be rude, just wondering why exactly its slower. Is it because I am connecting to MySQL twice? Does it effectively take double the time?

Comment: You can first run query `select * from table where username=?` if this query returns 1, so username is already used. if it returns 0 notes it you can check for emails. it's bad for performance because you have to run 2 queries instead of one.

Comment: Glad I'm getting such great responses from this question. I'll leave it for a bit just to see if I gather any more helpful opinions that will aid in my decision. I'm probably going to spend more time working out what option will be fastest than it would take to change the system, however its valuable knowledge for the future :).

Answer (score 3):

Run your query with OR and check the returned results to report what exactly you've found.

However, depending on database internals and indexing, two separate queries might be even faster than OR'ed together. You'd better benchmark all cases (found one, found both, found none) for definite answer about your environment.

Comment: Ahh. So instead of just relying on the number of rows returned, actually analyse the data?

Answer (score 2):

In database where you are keeping user's information make the username and email entity unique. Like primary key.

Comment: Username and email are indexed. Therefore unique index will not work. As far as I know anyway.

Comment: Both usernames and emails can be unique; the OP just wanted to know which of these is (potentially) repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is good; You will have 1 or 2 result; 2 if a registration exists with only the email or only the nickname; 1 if a registration has the email and nickname; use JS and specify the reasons on the right of the input fields

Comment: Currently I am using a simple template engine I wrote, but I see your point about the JS. What I am doing will effectively do the same thing but at the top of the form in red. Want it as obvious as possible. Plus the registration form is very small, only a few inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose that would be the simplest way:

```
SELECT IF(username = :username_to_check, 1, 0) AS dup_username
  FROM users
 WHERE username = :username_to_check OR email = :email_to_check
```

Then you check: 1) the number of rows - if it's 0, no duplicates were found; 2) the dup_username flag of your result, if rows count > 0.

Here's [an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6607/6) to play with.

Comment: I like this. There are a lot of factors to consider really, such as will more resources be used running two queries or a analysing a query with an if statement. A lot for me to consider here. Thought my question was simpler than it is.

Comment: As far as I know, the CASE/IF statements in SELECT clause would be applied only to the result set (already filtered by 'WHERE') - in other words, to one or zero rows, if your table is constrainted properly. So I don't think it'll be slower: would be great to check it on the huge DB to prove or bust it, though. )

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its bad for performance

if you have select query that is getting one row from table;  of lets say thousands rows ; then the impact is not to be mentioned at all..

What effect your performance is join queries which needs a lot of resources which isn't happening at your case ...

I believe its safe to use it separately, we've been doing it on our website which currently have over one million users

also try to run this query in your mysql server and see how long it takes this can help (especially for more complicated queries )

Comment: Problem is, I think it would be useless to trial the queries on my database with only  a small amount of dummy content in it. I would have to fill it will a few hundred thousand rows and see how it goes, but still it is not an acurate depication of a real life scenario. The site may never reach > 100000 users.

Comment: Again as I said in my answer, your query is safe ...and it wont effect your site or slow it down  .... 
queries was made for the purpose of using it (and your concern are far from what make things bad or messed up )  so relax  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Username = ''", $link);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Email= ''", $link);
    $num_rows2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

    $checkUsrN = false;
    $checkEmail = false;
    $mesg = "The following is bad: ";

    if($num_rows == 0)
    {
       $checkUsrN = true;         
    }
    else{
        $mesg .= "Username";
    }

    if($num_rows2 == 0)
    {
       $checkEmail = true;
    }
    else{
        $mesg .= "Email";
    }

    if($checkUsrN == false || $checkEmail == false)
    {
       echo $mesg;
       break;
    }
```

How is that for your purpose?

Comment: By having the email check in an else statement doesn't that mean that the email will only be checked if the username is valid? It would be entirely possible for a new user to register with an already existing username as well as an existing email from another user. Meaning they would have to submit the form twice.

Comment: Yes, the fist part is correct, but should the username be invalid, it will kick out, else it will check the email, if that is bad, it will also kick out. Check my edit to see an alternative.